# Unexpected behavior when changing values in multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array

I use the following function to create a multidimensional list of shape `dimension`:

```
def create(dimensions, elem):
    res = elem
    for i in dimensions[::-1]:
        res = [copyhelp(res) for _ in range(i)]
    return res.copy()

def copyhelp(r): #when res begins as elem, it has no .copy() function
    if isinstance(r,list):
        return r.copy()
    return r
```

So if I say `mylist = create([3,3,2],0)`, I get

```
  >> mylist
  [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Great. Now I use this function to change the value at an index given by a list `index` to `v`:

```
def replacor(array, index, v):
    if not isinstance(array[0],list):
        array[index[0]] = v
    else:
        return replacor(array[index[0]], index[1:], v)
```

Now when I do `replacor(mylist, [1,2,0], '.')`, I get this:

```
  >> mylist
  [[['.', 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [['.', 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [['.', 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

I'm suspicious it has to do with array pointers, but I used `copy()` at every step, so I'm not sure where I went wrong. Clearly the issue is the way I define my first list, but I still don't understand why I'm getting this behavior since ints, bools, and strings are immutable.

Comment: Your `copy` is in the wrong place. `([res]*i).copy()` is pointless, and so is `return res.copy()`.  `[res]*i` already *produces a new list*. The problem is that that list simply contains `i` references to the object referenced by `res`. You have to do something like `[res.copy() for _ in range(i)]`. Note this is not an array, but a *list*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried this, but I'm, getting the same issue. Clearly the issue is the way I define my first list, but I still don't understand why I'm getting this behavior since ints, bools, and strings are immutable. At what point is shallow copying taking place?

Comment: Your modified code doesn't run.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My bad, I "fixed" it but have the same problem.

Comment: You're making shallow copies when you need deep copies (but relying on copying for this is a bad idea anyway; a recursive direct construction is simpler and faster, and avoids building a habit of relying on the flaky `copy.deepcopy`).

Comment: @user2357112 Can you explain what you mean by "recursive direct construction"? I thought this *was* a recursive approach.

Comment: Something along the lines of `return elem if not dimensions else [create(dimensions[1:], elem) for _ in range(dimensions[0])]`.

Comment: @user2357112 That's perfect! In general, will recursion avoid these issues when making copies of elements in lists of lists?

Comment: It's not really recursion that's the key. It's the fact that instead of trying to create one object and copy it N times, we instead run the creation procedure N times. Recursion just happens to be one of the most natural ways to apply that principle to arbitrarily deeply nested data structures.